# How to use UNIX commands in Perl? (to be used on a Windows machine)

Tags: windows, perl, batch-file, unix

I need to filter the content of one file (javasrc.txt) by the contents of a second file (OEMDS.txt). This needs to be done in a Windows environment. I don't know about Windows batchfiles, I know about UNIX commands, I'm new at Perl and I would like to make my life as easy as possible, so I have thought of writing a UNIX command, put "system()" around it and it should work.

Unfortunately it seems not to be that simple: the following Perl script refuses to work:

```
system("cat javasrc.txt | grep -v qx(cat OEMDS.txt) > javasrc_temp.txt");
```

I get error message:

```
grep: OEMDS.txt): No such file or directory
```

For your information: I have already used the following for launching the `cat` command:

```
- backticks
- $()
- qx()
- qx{}
```

Always the result is the same: Perl seems to have an issue with the terminating character (the second backtick or comma, ...)

Now that I think about it, I launch this in the following way (I don't know if it's relevant):

```
perl filter_by_file_content.pl
```

Does anybody know what I can do?

Comment: run cygwin then (most) CLI unix commands will work as expected

Comment: @MarcB Or just use native Perl commands, since they can easily do the same work as `cat` and `grep`.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but both uses of `cat` in your command are completely unnecessary: `grep -vf OEMDS.txt javasrc.txt > javasrc_temp.txt` (I'm assuming OEMDS.txt contains a single line)

Comment: What is in `OEMDS.txt`?

Comment: I question why you expect "unix" commands like cat and grep to exist on a windows machine at all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Meanwhile I have a solution for my answer, it's actually more simple than I could imagine.

My reasoning was the following: I need to do something in batch (which I don't know), I know that Perl and Python can be used, I know my way around in UNIX commands and I know that Perl is capable of launching UNIX commands, hence my idea and the corresponding question.

However, the answer is much easier: I want to use `grep`, as this is the UNIX command I'm familiar with, but there is a Windows command which is very similar: `findstr`. Using this command I can easily obtain what I want:

```
findstr /V /G:OEMDS.txt javasrc.txt > javasrc_temp.txt
move /y javasrc_temp.txt javasrc.txt
```

Thank you all for the support, I've marked all your answers.

Comment: " know that Perl is capable of launching UNIX commands" perl can launch any OS command or program. Perl has grep built in, on every platform. You've wasted time shelling out to run other OS commands. It will take longer and is not portable.

Answer (score 3):

I'd probably just do something like this in perl - no `system` commands needed.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open ( my $exclude_list, '<', 'OEMDS.txt' ) or die $!; 
my $exclude_regex = join ( "|", map { s/[\r\n]//r } <$exclude_list> );
$exclude_regex = qr/($exclude_regex)/;
open ( my $src, '<', 'javasrc.txt' ) or die $!;
while ( <$src> ) { 
    print unless m/$exclude_regex/; 
}
```

Note - does mean that any meta characters in the exclude file will be treated as regular expressions. You can use `map { quotemeta }` if that's a problem.

Answer (score 1):

As @ThisSuitIsBlackNot suggests, do this in perl.  It's not a lot of code, and is likely to be faster anyway:

```
my $oemds = do {
    open my $fh, '<', 'OEMDS.txt' or die "Can't read OEMDS.txt: $!";
    local $/; # probably not required.
    <$fh>;
};
chomp $oemds;

open my $js, '<', 'javasrc.txt' or die "Can't read javasrc.txt: $!";

my @filtered;
while(<$js>) {
    chomp;
    next if /$oemds/; # grep -v
    push @filtered, $_;
}
close $js;

# write to javasrc_temp.txt if really required
```

I'm suspecting you really want the filtered lines in your program, not in a temp file, and this avoids the temp file.